# jquery performance td replace

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I need to manipulate a complex table for print.

My code works but on IE it runs for 10 sec (50 rows table)

How can I improve the performance?

I found out that `$(item).html(title)` takes the most time, how can I avoid this?

Thanks

The Code:

```
            tblTBLRows.find("td[name=tdTBLTitle]").each(function (i, item) {
            var title = "";
            if ($(item).find("*[name=iconForApprove]").length > 0) { title += "<b>[" + msgStatusForApprove + "]</b>&nbsp;" }
            if ($(item).find("*[name=iconComplete]").length > 0) { title += "<b>[" + msgStatusCompleted + "]</b>&nbsp;" }
            title += $(item).find("#contTxtTitle").html();
            $(item).html(title).removeClass("tdTBLTitle");
        });
```

Html: one row example:

```
 <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td name="tdTBLTitle" class="tdTBLTitle txtRight" colid="3">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tblTskTitle"><tbody><tr>
            <td> 
                <span class="icon_24 iconVGray" name="iconForApprove" title="...">&nbsp;</span> 
                <span class="spacer5">&nbsp;</span>
            </td>
            <td class="tdTxtTitle " name="txtTitle">
                <a href="..." class="NoLnk">
                    <div class="contTxtTitle Pointer" id="contTxtTitle">
                        Title1
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>   
            <td class="tdDescLast" name="txtDescLast">
                <a href="..." class="NoLnk">
                    <div class="contDescLast Pointer" id="contDescLast">
                        Title2
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @sirmorne , don't do .html in the loop its a costly operation , make your html final in a string and then do a .html in out of the loop

Comment: and if you're searching for an `id` you don't need to search in any context, as it's faster to just call `$('#whateverID')`, although for simple things, don't even use jQuery, `document.getElementById('whateverID').innerHTML` will return the text faster.

Comment: I know but how can build a string of just one TD in each row and then use it to replace all those TDs in all the rows? (the data is different in every row)

Comment: see my updated answer, might speed things up...

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. Somehow I need to build a string for the entire table and then replace all the TDs, but I don't see how it can be done.

Comment: I don't understand. You have a table element (TD) that has the ID "tdTBLTitle", in which resides a table. You pull out some "title" information from this inner table and replace the whole of this inner table by the title text. You are only doing this for one TD in the outer table, since all IDs have to be distinct. So why does this simple operation take 10 seconds, or am I missing something!

Comment: I'm doing this for all the TDs in the outer table with same name, (see edit - .find("td[name=tdTBLTitle]"))

Answer (score 3):

An important thing is to cache your jquery object references..

instead of calling multiple times the `$(item)` do `var $item = $(item);` and use that like `$item.find(..)`

Also keep in  mind that the `*` selector is very expensive.

If you know you will be looking for spans or some other specific tag use that instead.
For example `$item.find('span[name=iconForApprove]')`

Comment: For example, if `iconForApprove` is always on a span, change the selector to: `span[name=iconForApprove]`. Otherwise the browser literally checks every node to see if it has the correct name rather than just checking the spans.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using an array to build the string. IE often has very poor performance when concatenating strings.

```
var buffer = [];
buffer.push("string"); // add a bunch of stuff
var title = buffer.join('');
```

There is evidence that this doesn't make a big difference, but I recently used this for a huge performance gain in IE 7.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but $item.html(title) is the main problem.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. Thankfully, there are tons of other great suggestions for you to try!

Answer (score 0):

```
        tblTBLRows.find("#tdTBLTitle").each(function (i, item) {
        var title = "";
        if ($(item).find("*[name=iconForApprove]").length > 0) { title += "<b>[" + msgStatusForApprove + "]</b>&nbsp;" }
        if ($(item).find("*[name=iconComplete]").length > 0) { title += "<b>[" + msgStatusCompleted + "]</b>&nbsp;" }
        title += $(item).find("#contTxtTitle").html();
        $(item).html(title).removeClass("tdTBLTitle");
})
```

I'd suggest changing the `*` (universal selector) to the specific element that you're looking to find, which seems to be `span` in this example. That way jQuery's only looking at specific element-types, rather than looking at, and evaluating, *every* element it finds:

```
        tblTBLRows.find("#tdTBLTitle").each(function (i, item) {
        var title = "";
        if ($(item).find("span[name=iconForApprove]").length > 0) { title += "<b>[" + msgStatusForApprove + "]</b>&nbsp;" }
        if ($(item).find("span[name=iconComplete]").length > 0) { title += "<b>[" + msgStatusCompleted + "]</b>&nbsp;" }
        title += $(item).find("#contTxtTitle").html();
        $(item).html(title).removeClass("tdTBLTitle");
})
```

I'm not sure, though, how much time this could save you; it might well be a micro-optimisation and, if you're not sure that the elements you want will always be a `span`, it might not be possible in your situation anyway.